# Different styles for certain elements when wrapped in another element

Tags: html, css

I have the following styles for lists:

```
li {
background: rgb(66, 66, 66);
color:white;}    
ul {
background: rgb(66, 66, 66);
color:white;}
```

In addition, I have a div element with id `not_important_name` that contains a list, for which I need another style to be applied:

```
li {
background: rgb(144, 144, 144);
color:white;}    
ul {
background: rgb(144, 144, 144);
color:white;}
```

How can I override the first set of styles, only for lists inside the `not_important_name` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your CSS more specific. Please read about css selectors here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

In your case, u could do:

```
ul, li {
    /* CSS HERE */
}
div#not_important_name ul, div#not_important_name li {
    /* CSS HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need an excepton in the css style sheed for that div for li and ul

The standard way to go about this is to indicate in the markup that the container plays a specific role on the page:

```
<div class="exception">
```

and then declare the exceptional style rules in the stylesheet cascade either immediately below or some distance below the general rules.

```
.exception li {
background: rgb(144, 144, 144);
color:white;
}

.exception ul {
background: rgb(144, 144, 144);
color:white;
}
```